# Red shift/Blue shift as a standard for determining absolute motion

Tags: reference-frames, inertial-frames, inertia

If I begin standing, I can imagine that there are photons of various wavelengths arriving at my location from all directions.  If we eliminate local energy coming from stars and radiating bodies, there should still be a level of background radiation arriving at my location.  That should be very homogeneous coming from all directions.  If I start to move relative to my initial state, won't I encounter a blue shifting of those photons coming from the direction I am now moving (relative to my initial motion) and a red shift toward my back?  This seems to me that it would create an asymmetry, and also a force that would cause me to slow back down to the initial state.

Comment: So motion relative to the sources of radiation, not absolute motion.

Comment: Are you talking about the cosmic microwave background (CMB) as your "background radiation" that is "very homogeneous"?  If so, what makes you think that it won't also be equally homogeneous if you start walking east, or north, or hop in a space rocket, or stand on the moon?

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer yes equally homogeneous, but the photons hitting you in the front would be blueshifted and the ones hitting you in the back would be redshifted relative to your initial state of motion.  I could imagine this as a mechanism of time dilation and length contraction as well as possibly inertial mass.

Comment: @ConnorBehan well, you could assign every possible observer a velocity vector that they could all agree upon for each other.  You can't ever reach the source radiating the background radiation because it is regressing at near c.

Comment: You can also tell every possible observer to measure their velocity relative to Earth, same thing. That does not make the motion absolute.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, measurements of the CMB try to find the frame where it is the most homogeneous. That could be called CMB frame. It is as valid as any other frame according to general relativity.

As electromagnetic radiation carries momentum, it is true that if there were no stars, galaxies, planets, comets, black holes, and EM coming from them, the weak CMB momentum would act as a drag force on any object moving in its frame.